# Data types and declarations in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have tried to research this topic but I have come up with nothing,

Lets say I have a property declared in my .h like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *rootViewController;
```

and say in my .m I have alloc'd and inited like this:

```
self.rootViewController = [[MyCustomViewControllerClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyCustomViewControllerClass" bundle:nil];
```

This seems to compile and work correctly, however I'm really curious what the implication is of declaring the property type as the super class UIViewController, but Alloc and initing as the subclass of UIViewController MyCustomViewControlerClass?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end result is that you can assign any subclass of `UIViewController` to that property because any subclass of `UIViewController` will have all the same methods and properties as the base `UIViewController`, however, Xcode will complain about any methods or properties you're trying to access which aren't on a base `UIViewController`.

At run-time, this won't be a problem, so long as what you've actually assigned to this responds to those messages... but better programming suggests that at the very least, you write a protocol that includes those methods/properties and mark the property as conforming to that protocol.  In this case, you could use `@property NSObject<FooProtocol> *iVar;` and Xcode won't complain about calling any of the methods/properties in `FooProtocol`, but it will also only let you assign an object to that property if it conforms to `FooProtocol`.

Good programming calls for you to write your code in a way in which the compiler doesn't even flag warnings.  It forces any future maintainer of your code to stop and scratch their head and figure out whether or not it's something that should be fixed (and it is something that should be fixed).

Answer (score 1):

The implication is that Xcode will only autocomplete UIViewController methods for you. At runtime, the object will still be a MyCustomController.  Your property could declare it as NSObject, or id, and the same behavior would occur.